# adding jquery plugin in ELGG

Tags: jquery, elgg

Im new to php & elgg as well.. I am learning elgg plugin development , I have developed event plugin in elgg which working fine,event plugin allows to admin add an event details which can be displayed in EVENT menu, but now i want to show this details to user s i jquery grid format but I dont know how to do it, I have tried with registering jquery files in start.php file but not working ..so can you please help me how to add jquery in elgg plugin,,I already wasted 1 week to do this but worked,,,I am hoping quick response fron you before I give up..
Thanks in advance..

![event deails,which I wnat show as jquery grid][1]

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Post your code, please.
Jquery is in Elgg core yet, you can register an external javascript file using `elgg_register_js` function so you can use jquery function from your js files.